# Confusion with the usage of addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to customize the FlatDatePicker from https://github.com/christopherney/FlatDatePicker.

My goal is to remove the two buttons from the top of the datepicker and add a confirm button to the bottom of screen which is as wide. In the original FlatDatePicker.m file, the author used the following code to initialize the datepicker, the tile, and the button:

```
if ([self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _parentView.frame.size.height, _parentView.frame.size.width, kFlatDatePickerHeight)]) {
    _datePickerMode = FlatDatePickerModeDate;
    [_parentView addSubview:self];
    [self setupControl];
}
return self;

_labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kFlatDatePickerButtonHeaderWidth, 0.0, self.frame.size.width - (kFlatDatePickerHeaderHeight * 2), kFlatDatePickerHeaderHeight)];

_buttonValid = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - kFlatDatePickerButtonHeaderWidth, 0.0, kFlatDatePickerButtonHeaderWidth, kFlatDatePickerHeaderHeight)];
```

Then a show method will be called to slide up the datepicker from off the the screen:

```
-(void)show {

if (_parentView != nil) {

    if (self.hidden == YES) {
        self.hidden = NO;
    }

    if (_isInitialized == NO) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, _parentView.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        _isInitialized = YES;
    }

    if (self.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDate ||
        self.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDateAndTime ||
        self.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeMonthAndYear) {

        if ( self.datePickerMode != FlatDatePickerModeMonthAndYear ) {
            int indexDays = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewDays];
            [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsDays atIndex:indexDays];
        }

        int indexMonths = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewMonths];
        [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsMonths atIndex:indexMonths];

        int indexYears = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewYears];
        [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsYears atIndex:indexYears];
    }

    if (self.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeTime || self.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDateAndTime) {

        int indexHours = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewHours];
        [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsHours atIndex:indexHours];

        int indexMinutes = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewMinutes];
        [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsMinutes atIndex:indexMinutes];

        int indexSeconds = [self getIndexForScrollViewPosition:_scollViewSeconds];
        [self highlightLabelInArray:_labelsSeconds atIndex:indexSeconds];
    }

    if (IS_PHONE) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"FlatDatePickerShow" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kFlatDatePickerAnimationDuration];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationShowDidFinish)];
    }

    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, _parentView.frame.size.height - kFlatDatePickerHeight, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    if (IS_PHONE) [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}

Since the initial y coordinates of the button and title is set to 0.0 and that of the datepicker is _parentView.frame.size.height which is the bottom of the screen, how come they are brought next to each other after running the "show" method???

Also, there's another issue when I try to use the following code to add a confirm button right below the datepicker:

```
_buttonValid = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, kFlatDatePickerHeaderHeight)];
[self addSubview:_buttonValid]
```

After running the button was added to the right place but there's no response when pressing it (which never happened before the button's position was changed).